# Writing a AJAX Post HTTP Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm currently working on getting a front-end connected to an API, and I'm sure I'm getting the following error due to a malformed body giving information not how the API wants.

[image: jQuery error response in console.]

This is how I used postman to get the data from the API:

[image: Postman snip]

In Postman, the body is simply:

```
{
"person" : "Jose Soto",
"connection":"Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=people;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
}
```

and the response comes back fine. I'm sure I've miswritten the $.ajax() call wrong. Here's the call:

```
  $.ajax({
  'type' : 'POST',
  'url' : '/api/getpeople',
  'data' : {
    'person' : user,
    'connection' : app.connection
  },
    'success' : function(data){
      data.name = '${data.fName} ${data.lName}';
      app.userArray.push(data.name);
      app.ppl.push({
        'name' : data.name,
```

and so on....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var send = '{"person" : "Jose Soto", "connection":"DataSource(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;InitialCatalog=people;IntegratedSecurity=True;ConnectTimeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;AppicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"}';

$.ajax({
    url: "/api/getpeople",
    type: "POST"
    data: send,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(json){
        //success 
    }
 )};
```

This more like what you need, I believe you need to add a `contentType`

Comment: I fixed the quotes for you

Comment: Noticed you also beat me too! - have an upvote @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: now, it's giving a 404 response.... but it's being served from port 5000 like the rest of my site. (Postman still works now that I'm testing on 5000 with that as well.

Comment: 404 is not found, is your HTML/JS page in the same project/location/path as your api controller? @ChrisRutherford

Answer (score 1):

In Postman you're explicitly sending JSON, whereas by default `$.ajax` will send the data as form-urlencoded. The error code and description would also imply that the API is not expecting data in the format you're sending.

To change this add `contentType: 'application/json'` to the `$.ajax` settings.

Comment: Nice! Thanks!  testing this now.

Comment: @ChrisRutherford note that you may need to use a full path instead of a relative one if the port setting of the API is different to that of the website

Comment: Site is being served from ASP.Net core, and I'm viewing the site from the same port. (UseStaticFiles) so the port isn't an issue.